# Views return html from another app in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to show a data with different feature .. So, there are 2 role where admin have 5 columns on the table. when the teacher only have 4 columns on the table. I change the HTML already but when I return classlist.html on teacherpage views.py .. it return the admin classlist.html that have 5 columns on the table.

Here is my code :

Urls.py (Teacher APP):

```
from django.urls import path
from teacherpage import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('classlist/', views.classlist, name='classlist'),
]
```

Views.py (Teacher APP):

```
def classlist(request):
    data = classModel.objects.all()
    classlist= {
        "classlist" : data
    }
    return render(request,'classlist.html', classlist)
```

Comment: Create separate templates and render template based on condition.

Comment: I tried. but same thing happened. i just did something that make it worked. i make a different url for both page .. it worked. but i want same url :(

Comment: You code is not showing roles types. Otherwise i would have given solution in the asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complicated without the actual codes of the project from you, but here is an idea about how you can use the same view and same html file for two different tables. For example, if your user's role is stored in the [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) model, then you can use this code in classlist.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% if user.role == 'admin' %}
    <table with five columns>
{% else %}
    <table with four columns>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
    no table for you
{% endif %}
```

FYI, you do not need to modify any views or urls to make it work.